# Can the pdf of the difference of two independent random variables be found out using their Probability Generation Functions?

Tags: probability, probability-generating-fn, discrete-distributions

I recently learned of probability generation functions and that the sum of two independent random variables can be found out by multiplying the PGFs. I wanted to know if anything similar can be done for the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, let $A=X-Y$ and $G_X(z),G_Y(z)$ be PGFs of $X,Y$ respectively, then:
$$G_A(z)=E[z^{X-Y}]=E[z^X]E[(1/z)^Y]=G_X(z)G_Y(1/z)$$

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: I tried up voting, but it said votes cast by people with less than 15 reputation are recorded but not publicly displayed!!

Comment: thanks, you can accept the answer by clicking the tick sign  under the arrow in my answer

Comment: Done!! Thank you again.